# pageMod event to listen to response from panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have two content scripts:

1. annotationEditor (panel)
2. editField (pageMod)

The addon first asks the user to enter some text in a popup panel created by annotationEditor. This is working perfectly. The text is returned in the variable `annotationText`. `annotationText` is stored as the global variable `savedText` so that editField has access to it.

Then I want editField to take `savedText` and do something with it (append it to an input field). The problem is that I am having is that the pageMod event onAttach is called when the page loads, not after the "text is saved". I also can't find any other events for the [`PageMod` Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Events). So `worker.port.emit("editel", [this.annotationAnchor, savedText])` doesn't work either.

```
var annotationEditor = panels.Panel({
    width: 220,
    height: 220,
    contentURL: data.url('editor/annotation-editor.html'),
    contentScriptFile: data.url('editor/annotation-editor.js'),
    onMessage: function(annotationText) {
        if (annotationText) {
            // handleNewAnnotation(annotationText, this.annotationAnchor);
            savedText = annotationText;
            annotationEditor.hide();
        }
        annotationEditor.hide();
    },
    onShow: function() {
        this.postMessage('focus');
    }
});

var editField = pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.8.3.min.js'), data.url('edit.js')],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.emit("editel", [this.annotationAnchor, savedText]);
    }
});
```

Try 2: Is this closer?
Still doesn't seem to be working right. I am not picking up any message in the `edit.js` content script.

```
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var editors = [];

function getEditor(tab) {
for (var i = editors.length; i--;)
    if (editors[i].tab===tab) return editors[i];
}

var annotationEditor = panels.Panel({
    width: 220,
    height: 220,
    contentURL: data.url('editor/annotation-editor.html'),
    contentScriptFile: data.url('editor/annotation-editor.js'),
    onMessage: function(annotationText) {
        if (annotationText) {
            var currentEditor = getEditor(tabs.activeTab);
            console.log(currentEditor)
            currentEditor.port.emit("editel",[this.annotationAnchor, annotationText]); 
            annotationEditor.hide();
        }
        annotationEditor.hide();
    },
    onShow: function() {
        this.postMessage('focus');
    }
});

var editField = pageMod.PageMod({
include: ['*'],
contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.8.3.min.js'),
                    data.url('edit.js')],
onAttach: function(worker) {
    editors.push(worker);
    worker.on('detach', function () {
        detachWorker(this, selectors);
    });
}
});
```

This logs `currentEditor` as:

```
constructor {"contentScriptFile":["resource://jid1-kpzxxdxlwq8qkg-at-jetpack/widget/data/jquery-1.8.3.min.js","resource://jid1-kpzxxdxlwq8qkg-at-jetpack/widget/data/edit.js"],"contentScript":null,"port":{}}
```

Does that look right?

Also here is the content script- `edit.js`. Obviously right now it doesn't do much. First step is to get it to catch the message from `main.js`.

```
self.port.on("editEl", function(el) {
$(el[1]).val(el[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the worker a global variable. Then do `worker.port.emit` in the Panel's `onMessage`.

---

Edit: a better approach is to create an array of workers as shown in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Destroying_Workers) in the docs. Then, to find the current tab's worker later on you can do the following:

```
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

var getWorker = function(tab) {
  for (var i = workers.length; i--;)
    if (workers[i].tab===tab) return workers[i];
}

var currentWorker = getWorker(tabs.activeTab);
```

Comment: So basically what you are saying is I declare the worker as a global variable, then I define it in the `editField` `onAttach` event, and finally I call it in the `annotationEditor` `onMessage` event?

Comment: Correct. But that's a very naive approach, as you're going to have more than one worker. The documentation for the SDK is very good, and it's worth reading their examples. On the same page you linked to, there's [a great example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Destroying_Workers) of how to manage multiple workers.

Comment: Would you be able to take a look at a second attempt in the code above?! thx

Comment: Any chance you could give my code another look. I updated it to try and include your suggestions.

Comment: You're emitting `"editel"`, but listening for `"editEl"` (capital E). The strings need to be the identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot that finally did it!